# Trouble creating a pie chart in R

Tags: r, pie-chart

I just started using R software and I'm having some issues making graphs/charts. I'm using the data from this website as a sample: http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/CPS_85_Wages

I put the variable names above the correct columns, and the imported it to R using

```
mydata = read.table("proj1.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
```

I want to start off by just making a pie chart for the categorical data like south, sex, etc. But I've tried everything and can't seem to find any information online to help me. The few pie graphs I've gotten to show have been giant black and white blobs with no information on them. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried

```
sex = table(mydata$SEX)
pie(sex)
```

and I get the error

> "Error in seq.int(x[i], x[i + 1], length.out = n) :    'length.out'
>   must be a non-negative number"

1 = Female and 0 = Male in the data, but I can worry about that later.

Comment: No information on line? Try http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/pie.html (my first hit when googling "pie chart R")

Comment: I understand if you manually add the information in. But I imported the data from a .txt file. It's a bunch of rows, with variable names at the top of each column, and the data below it corresponds with it. I figured if I did something like pie(SOUTH) it would create just a very basic, no-label graph. But that just says "object 'SOUTH' not found"

Comment: what you have is a data.frame, look at the last example in the link.

Comment: I'm getting this error "Error in seq.int(x[i], x[i + 1], length.out = n) : 
  'length.out' must be a non-negative number" 
After I put in sex = table(mydata$SEX) and then pie(sex).

Comment: Why not edit the question and clarify what error you are getting....

Comment: Never EVER use pie charts.  They provide the least information over the greatest (wasted) space of any graphical format.

Answer (score 1):

The data as it stands cannot simply be read using `read.table("proj1.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")`.

Currently my guess is that `sex` is an empty table

```
print(sex) 
##  < table of extent 0 >
```

Reading straight from the webpage

```
mydata <- read.table('http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/CPS_85_Wages', 
                     sep='\t', header=FALSE,skip=27,nrows=562-28)
```

but this does not include the column names. You can get these from the header to the file with a bit of cleaning

```
myheader <- readLines('http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/CPS_85_Wages',n=26)
# get the lines that correspond with the definitions.
vars <- tail(myheader,length(mydata))
# set names with scrubbed text
names(mydata) <- gsub(':.+|\t','',vars)
# now 
sex = table(mydata$SEX)
pie(sex, labels = c('Male','Female') )
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help! One question, I don't understand what this means:

vars <- tail(myheader,length(mydata))
# set names with scrubbed text
names(mydata) <- gsub(':.+|\t','',vars)

Comment: Comne on, mnel has already done the hard bit for you. If you don't understand a fragment of code, break the line into its components, then go through each function in the code and look them up e.g. `?tail`, `?length`, `?gsub`. You're here to learn, not to be spoonfed.